# How do I insert a new row with the silverlight 3 DataGrid (and not use the DataForm)?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, ria

In silverlight 2 it was possible to add new rows to the collection through the DataGrid. But in silverlight 3 I cannot figure out how to do this without using a DataForm. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank to the source

```
lst = New genericList With { _
                      .field1 = "", _
                      .field2 = "", _
                      .field3 = "", _
                      .field4 = ""}
rtnlst.Add(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck in the past simply adding a blank row to the data source and then checking for non-null values when the datagrid is updated.  The user can just click in the empty row and add the information and the update routine can insert the values from there.